# In minecraft, How do i set a spawnpoint using command blocks

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a parkour course and I want to have the player respawn at every new checkpoint they reach when they die

Comment: This is pretty easy to search online. Please do some research before posting on Arqade.

Answer (score -1):

Easy, get a command block where you can step on (suggesting pressure plate), and type the following command:

```
spawnpoint @p x y z
```

Fill `x y z` to your desired coordinates.

But there's a better way, though I don't suggest using it. Try:

```
execute @a[x=#,z=#,dx=0,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ spawnpoint @s ~ ~ ~
```

Replace the `#` with your desired coordinates.

This has to be done via an Always Active Repeating Command Block, and you don't need to make some redstone for this to work. Let the command block do it's job and it will be automatic for everyone.

Just remember that you must make the coordinates exact (as suggested by [**@Penguin**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/258509/penguin)).

Comment: Wait that last one is actually really clever, although I'd suggest instead of relative coords just punching in the exact ones as to avoid decimals

Comment: The second method you gave is somewhat impractical. The player has to be at the exact x and z coordinates for the command to work. Also, if you're using dx and dz equal to 0, you don't need them at all. However, your first method works fine.